# Retrieve Youtube Shows rss feed

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

Does anyone know a way to retrieve the RSS feed of a show. There are episodes released for this show, I was wondering if there is any way to retrieve an xml or some sort of RSS feed with the updates. Sample show link is http://www.youtube.com/show/beachgirlz/videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question! You can get that, but it is a bit of a challenge actually getting what you are looking for.

Here is an example of the goal: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/seasons/JQEfvHcfJjY/episodes?v=2

The problem is how you get there!

This is how I got to that point.

1. Find out the user who creates the show and use the following URL to access the shows that the user creates. https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/shows?v=2
2. Narrow it down to the show you want and go to the feed for that show. https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/shows/SHOW_ID/content?v=2
3. From there you can narrow it down to a season and finally get your feed of episodes. https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/seasons/SEASON_ID/episodes?v=2